# Publish network services using Systemd machinectl

Tags: systemd, chroot, containers

**TL;DR**: How to expose network services to the host through machinectl/nspawn containers?

I'm trying to make things perfectfor my setup, i.e. installing my services in separated *chroot* instances.

To start them, I want to comply with SystemD management with `systemd-nspawn` and `machinectl`:

```
# debootstrap stretch /var/lib/machines/mymachine
# machinectl start mymachine # works well!
# machinectl shell root@mymachine bash
```

Then I install dummy `apache2` on it:

```
 (jail)# apt install -y apache2 && systemctl enable apache2 && systemctl start apache2
 (jail)# ss -tnlp | grep 80 # yields apache2 running.
```

However, the 80 port (or even *any* port whatsoever, say 8080) is not visible on listening on the host. How to make it work ?

Thank you team,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an [nspawn](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.nspawn.html) file for the machine that exposes the port.

> [Network] Section Options
>
> Port= Exposes a TCP or UDP port of the
> container on the host. This option corresponds to the --port= command
> line switch, see systemd-nspawn(1) for the precise syntax of the
> argument this option takes. This option is privileged (see above).

From systemd-nspawn(1):

> -p, --port= If private networking is enabled, maps an IP port on the host onto an IP port on the container. Takes a protocol specifier
> (either "tcp" or "udp"), separated by a colon from a host port number
> in the range 1 to 65535, separated by a colon from a container port
> number in the range from 1 to 65535. The protocol specifier and its
> separating colon may be omitted, in which case "tcp" is assumed. The
> container port number and its colon may be omitted, in which case the
> same port as the host port is implied. This option is only supported
> if private networking is used, such as with --network-veth,
> --network-zone= --network-bridge=.

The [systemd-nspawn@.service unit](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/units/systemd-nspawn%40.service.in) uses `--network-veth`

So something like

```
[Network]
Port=80
```

should work.

Answer (score 1):

I just run `systemd-nspawn` without any network flags, it uses host networking - then route my web app's port using nginx.

Assume `$MACHINE_NAME` is `webapp` in this instance:

```
systemd-nspawn -D /var/lib/machines/webapp -M webapp --chdir=/ ./entrypoint &
```

- `-D` is the directory of the filesystem root,
- `-M` is the machine name,
- `--chdir` changes directory inside the container and
- `./entrypoint` is a script I want to run (this can be any command, script, etc.)
- `&` runs it in the background (so you can do other things in the particular tty you ran the command in).

The `entrypoint` script was originally from a podman container this filesystem was exported from. Here's what it's doing (it's very simple):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cd /home/localuser/webapp
npm run start
```

So this just runs the web app I developed inside the container.  It's designated to run on port `3000`.

Then, nginx is set up to proxy `80` for `3000`, which has an open port in the firewall:

```
# cat /etc/nginx/sites-available/webapp
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name webapp.xyz;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass         "http://127.0.0.1:3000";
    }
}
```

You can see it's using the loopback device - but any of your host networking is available inside the container when `systemd-nspawn` is run *without* `--boot`, and *without* `--network-{bridge,interface,ipvlan,macvlan,veth}`. It's very similar to `chroot` this way.

Then, once `systemd-nspawn` is running (in the background because `&` is at the end of the command), one can run:

```
machinectl enable $MACHINE_NAME
```

and it will generate a symlink with the name of the machine from an `.nspawn` template.

`.nspawn` template is here: `/lib/systemd/system/systemd-nspawn@.service`

`$MACHINE_NAME.nspawn` link will be added here: `/etc/systemd/system/machines.target.wants/systemd-nspawn@$MACHINE_NAME.service`

If you want to default to running new machines using host networking, just backup the original and remove some of the runtime arguments:

```
/* backup original unit file */

# mv /lib/systemd/system/systemd-nspawn@.service \
     /lib/systemd/system/systemd-nspawn@.service.orig

/* echo a more simple file into its place */

# echo '[Unit]
Description=Container %i
Documentation=man:systemd-nspawn(1)
Wants=modprobe@loop.service
PartOf=machines.target
Before=machines.target
After=systemd-resolved.service modprobe@loop.service
RequiresMountsFor=/var/lib/machines/%i

[Service]
ExecStart=systemd-nspawn --quiet --keep-unit --link-journal=try-host --machine=%i --chdir=/ ./entrypoint
KillMode=mixed
Type=notify
RestartForceExitStatus=133
SuccessExitStatus=133
Slice=machine.slice
Delegate=yes
TasksMax=16384
WatchdogSec=3min

DeviceAllow=char-pts rw
DeviceAllow=/dev/loop-control rw
DeviceAllow=block-loop rw
DeviceAllow=block-blkext rw

# these two only nec. for LUKS - can remove 
DeviceAllow=/dev/mapper/control rw
DeviceAllow=block-device-mapper rw

[Install]
WantedBy=machines.target' > /lib/systemd/system/systemd-nspawn@.service
```

You can see here the command to run inside the unit file is essentially the same, I just added the flag `--link-journal=try-host`, which places a log at `/var/log/journal/$MACHINE_UUID` for monitoring the container.

Since this is a template, it assumes I'll be invoking a script named `entrypoint` from the root dir of each container, which gives them more of a 'command invoking container' behavior (e.g. Docker-style as opposed to LXC-style).

Notes about issues:

I'd like to use `--user` flag, but it appears to be non-functional ATM.  There's some [talk about a regression here](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/8194) regarding the flag, but it pertains to v237 on CentOS, so not sure if it relates to 241 on Ubuntu 20.04, which is what I'm using ATM. Anyhow, containers will run w/ root UID for now...

`systemd-networkd` is supposed to work with `--network-veth` to create a DHCP host on `host0` and client on `ve-$MACHINE_NAME` (limit 16 chars) - *IF* both the host and the client use `systemd-networkd`.  However, I have not been able to get this to work properly in practice on Ubuntu 20.04.  I'm guessing there's a bug re: this functionality in my version of systemd and will be doing further testing on later versions.

Environment info:

```
# cat /etc/os-release && systemd --version
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.2 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
systemd 245 (245.4-4ubuntu3.6)
+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD +IDN2 -IDN +PCRE2 default-hierarchy=hybrid
```

Further reading:

- [man systemd-nspawn](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-nspawn.html)
- [man systemd.nspawn (.nspawn file spec)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.nspawn.html)
- [man machinectl](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/machinectl.html)
- [arch wiki on systemd-nspawn](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/systemd-nspawn)